# How can I extract non-standard HTTP headers using Perl's LWP?

Tags: perl, http, header, lwp

I'm working with a web application that sends some non-standard HTTP headers in its response to a login request. The header in question is:

```
SSO_STATUS: LoginFailed
```

I tried to extract it with LWP::Response as `$response->header('SSO_STATUS')` but it does not work. It does work for standard headers such as `Set-Cookie`, `Expires` etc.

Is there a way to work with the raw headers?

Answer (score 7):

if you see the documentation of [HTTP::Headers](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP%3a%3aHeaders#NON-CANONICALIZED_FIELD_NAMES), it states that

> The header field name spelling is normally canonicalized 
>   including the '_' to '-' translation. There are some application where
>   this is not appropriate. Prefixing field names with ':' allow you to
>   force a specific spelling. For example if you really want a header field
>   name to show up as foo_bar instead of "Foo-Bar", you might set it like
>   this:

```
  $h->header(":foo_bar" => 1);
```

> These field names are returned with the ':' intact for
>   `$h->header_field_names` and the `$h->scan` callback, but the colons do
>   not show in `$h->as_string`.

Comment: I am not trying to set headers. I just want to read this non-standard header.

Answer (score 4):

See [this thread on Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=756540).

You need to access the value of the header field as `$response->header('SSO-STATUS')`.

The syntax for setting fields with underscores in names:
`$response->header(':SSO_STATUS' => 'foo');`

Comment: $response->headers_as_string get's all the headers, and I can do a regexp match on that, but it would be nice to have a cleaner way.